# Node (Express) request body empty

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I was working on a simple API using Node.JS and Restify tonight and had everything fine in terms of receiving parameters via `req.params.fieldname`. I installed CouchDB and Cradle in order to start trying to throw those parameters into a database, but after getting everything installed req.params started to come back empty!

I should have been using Express to begin with for other reasons, so I tried switching to that to see if I could get it working but no such luck.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Printomatic listening at', app.url);
});
```

I've tried countless variations but no matter what req.body comes back empty. I'm using http-console to test, and sending things as simple as `POST /` with content `{"name":"foobar"}`

I'm so frustrated that at this point I'm beginning to wonder if I broke something when installing Cradle/CouchDB (which were installed with NPM and Homebrew, respectively). Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is somewhat time-sensitive. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: what happens if you try app.get('/', function(req,res){res.send('Hello World');}; and then do a get request??

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You mention that you post JSON data (`{"name": "foobar"}`). Make sure that you send `Content-Type: application/json` with that, or `bodyParser` will not parse it.

E.g.:

```
$ curl -d 'user[name]=tj' http://local/
$ curl -d '{"user":{"name":"tj"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://local/
```

This is because `bodyParser` parses `application/json`, `application/x-www-form-encoded` and `multipart/form-data`, and it selects which parser to use based on the `Content-Type`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I was using http-console and I guess for some reason the headers changed! Thank you!

Comment: I was using Postman REST client and it worked when I used form-data but not when sending raw. Setting content type in the header fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Nikhil! I had the same issue with Postman, and we have to set the header: Content-Type (no colon) and Value: application/json

Comment: Saved me a lot of time and punches :). Thanks!