# flowjs to upload files POST request sends empty array

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, flow-js, ng-flow

I'm trying to use `flowjs`/`ng-flow` to upload images but I'm not getting anything on my backend.

This is the method that is supposed to receive the images in my Flask `routes.py`:

```
@app.route('/api/file/upload/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload_files():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print "GET"
        print request.args
    else:
        print "POST"
        print request.args

    return "200"
```

Before finding out that I had to set `testChunks:false`, I was receiving only a `GET` request and `request.args` looked like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('flowFilename', u'coldplay_butterfly.JPG'), ('flowTotalChunks', u'1'), ('flowRelativePath', u'coldplay_butterfly.JPG'), ('flowTotalSize', u'35338'), ('flowCurrentChunkSize', u'35338'), ('flowIdentifier', u'35338-coldplay_butterflyJPG'), ('flowChunkSize', u'1048576'), ('flowChunkNumber', u'1')])
```

As for the `POST`, I get this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I could also use some help on what to do after I get the array with the files, as in how to properly save the images to a folder inside my project. The only example I found was in PHP, so if someone could clarify how to do that in Python I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm having exactly the same problem.  I disabled testChunks in flow-init but I'm not receiving empty posts

Comment: Just found it.  You need to include a multipart middleware.  I got mine working using multer as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23439704/2340336

You will need to set `fileParameterName: 'profiles'` in flow/ng-flow and have multer look for a form of that name.